# How to check for an "undefined" test present in the string using regex-Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting an undefined attached to a string  at the end after a regex, something like:

```
var string="test.testA:(number:'1')undefined'
```

and sometimes it gets attached to the string as

```
var string2 = "test.testA:(number:'1') and undefined"
```

basically this could be anywhere and I wanted to remove this using regex. Does regex check if there is undefined present in the string? if not what is the best possible soln for this to remove the "undefined" test present in the string?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove just `undefined` or the whole string where it appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// remove only "undefined"
var test = [
    "test.testA:(number:'1')undefined",
    "test.testA:(number:'1') and undefined",
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.replace(/\bundefined\b/, '');
}));

// remove the whole line
var test2 = [
    "test.testA:(number:'1')undefined",
    "test.testA:(number:'1') and undefined",
];
console.log(test2.map(function (a) {
  return a.replace(/^.*?\bundefined\b.*$/, '');
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

For both of your example strings this will remove everything after the close paren in the string.

```
var foo = inputString.replace(/[\w\s]*undefined\s*$/i, '');
```

- \w - any of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _
- \s - spaces and tabs
- []*  - 0 or more of any pattern inside
- undefined - the literal "undefined"
- \s* - 0 or more spaces/tabs
- $ - end of the string
- i - everything inside // is case-insensitive (the word 'undefined', in this case)

If you're looking to remove the entire contents of the input if it contains the word undefined then [@Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto)'s answer is the way to go.

Comment: Just clarifying for OP, this will remove everything after the last symbol (i.e. close parens)